# Rails 5 - Import CSV with Images from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, file-upload, amazon-s3

Rails 5.1 -
Ruby 2.3.4 -
AWS S3 - Carrierwave & Minimagick

I would like to import a CSV file to my Rails app and also upload Images with each record.

The images are URL's from a current AWS S3 Bucket. I am able to upload from my local drive but only in development.

```
  def self.import(file)
    CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      Model.find_or_create_by(name: row[:name]) do |m|
        m.name = row[:name]
        m.description = row[:description]
        m.image = URI.parse(row[:image])
        m.summary = row[:summary]
      end
    end
  end
```

The CSV is simply

```
name,descripton,image,summary
Test,Test-Description,https://s3.amazonaws.com/main/production/model/7/image/image-formated.jpg,Test-Summary
```

Though whenever I try and upload on my live server. The images are not processed. How can I reference and upload the images correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I can't load the URL that you have but it should work with something like:

`m.image = URI.parse(row[:image]).open`

This will return a tempfile which Rails will associate to the model.

**Background:**

`URI.parse()` returns `URI::HTTPS` the url encoded URI for example:

```
URI.parse('https://google.com/search?q=test this')
# => #<URI::HTTPS https://google.com/search?q=test%20this> # where %20 is a url encoded space
```

So assuming your model expects an image file, you want to open and save the file rather than the URI. If this does not solve this, please share the config for your model

Comment: This solution did not work. The image is from my S3 bucket so I just put a generic URL for the above example. I am mounting an image uploader to a separate S3 bucket for my Import. I would like to use the image from the URL and upload it to the new bucket.

Comment: Can you share your model definition? How is m.image defined? what DB type?